# How to create a loop of get calls (axios) through a list and return the answer of all

Tags: javascript, list, get, axios, func

How to create a loop of get calls through a list and return the answer of all.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const id = ['234','9887']
axios.get(`https://myapi/api/id/${id}`, {
method: 'GET',
headers:{'xxxxxxxxxx': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
}})

      .then(function (response = response.json()) {
// handle success
console.log = (response.data)
     })
.catch(function (error) {
// handle error
console.log(error);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for.

I have changed your fake API for a real one, so you can test.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const id = ['234','9887']

const promArr = id.map(
  id =>
    axios.get(
      `https://postman-echo.com/get?key=${1234}`, 
      {
        method: 'GET',
        headers:{'xxxxxxxxxx': 'xxxxxxxxxxx',}
      }
    )
)

Promise.all(promArr)
  .then(function (responses) {
    // handle success
    responses.map(response => console.log(response.data))
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Marin.
Another doubt, if possible.
How do I limit the time between calls in one second?

Comment: This is not as simple as it looks... Though, it is possible. Try to implement something yourself, and put some effort, and always if you struggle write a question explaining where you are stuck.